# Unable to install the fabric plugin (for crashlytics) on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Unable to download the Fabric plugin on Android studio. I am able to download other plugins on the same network, so not an issue with the connectivity.

As an alternative, i tried manual installation of the plugin. But with manual installation, the plugin somehow does not launch  (ends with an exception).

So I am back to this. Is anyone else facing this issue ?

P.S - I am on Android Studio 2.2.2

[image]

P.S - Below is the crash log when i install the plugin manually and restart Android Studio (Some part of the crash stack removed for brevity)

Plugin 'com.crashlytics.tools.androidstudio' failed to initialize and will be disabled.  Please restart Android Studio.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of com/intellij/ide/plugins/cl/PluginClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of com/intellij/util/lang/UrlClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:299)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.bootstrap.osgi.OsgiBootstrapper.<clinit>(OsgiBootstrapper.java:54)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.CrashlyticsPlugin.initComponent(CrashlyticsPlugin.java:89)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:522)
    at
```

Comment: Facing same issue with Visual Studio Team Foundation plugin... Have you found any solution.